# Can I run order by with distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named emails which looks like this:

| customer_id | email_template_id | send_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-01-10 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-02-10 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-03-10 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-03-10 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-04-10 |

I want to order the data by email_template_id which will be given on the web page (can be 1,2,3...). Whenever a person clicks on sort by (template_id = 2), I want to retrieve the data order by template_id then by date, but still get the unique customer_id of course. The result should look something like this:

| customer_id | email_template_id | send_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-10 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-02-10 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-04-10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-01-10 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-03-10 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-03-10 |

I have tried this but I am getting duplicate rows.

```sql
select distinct customer_id as cust,email_template_id
from email_order 
ORDER by FIELD(email_template_id,3,1,2,4,5,6),send_time desc
```

I also tried to use group by, but it disturbs the order

```sql
select distinct customer_id as cust,email_template_id 
from email_order
group by customer_id
ORDER by FIELD(email_template_id,3,1,2,4,5,6),send_time desc
```

I am using MYSQL 4.7.5 version.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? Usually, you won't get any duplicated rows. Also, MySQL has never released a version 4.7.5

Comment: Also, if the result should contain the column `send_time`, why does your `SELECT` not contain that?

Comment: While you say you want your rows ordered by email_template_id and then by send_time, the result you are showing is ordered by customer_id first and only then by email_template_id (and send_time). If this is what you want, then simply `order by customer_id, email_template_id, send_time`. Then, why `DISTINCT`? Does your table really contain duplicates? Why? Can a customer send two emails with the same template at exactly the same time? That doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Actually it contains duplicates, because multiple email templates can be sent to a customer! So if we send him 5 email there will be 5 rows of same customer but with different email_template_id

Comment: `DISTINCT` removes duplicate rows. But there are no duplicate rows, because you want to select customer_id + email_template_id + send_time, and this combination is unique. There is nothing to remove in your query, so you should not use `DISTINCT`. And as to "I am still waiting for the solution by someone": You got an answer by Tim. And this is the same answer we all would give you. If this doesn't work for you, then explain in detail how this is different from what you need.

Comment: Your last edit changed your request completely. I've rolled it back, because that would be an entirely different question. Your question was about sorting and Tim has answered this. Accept his answer. If you have *another* question (your last edit mafe it look like you are looking for how to get the last row per customer) then ask another request. Or better yet look it up in stackoverflow or google, because the question how to get the top row per group has been asked over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output table implies the following query:

```sql
SELECT customer_id, email_template_id, send_time
FROM email_order 
ORDER BY customer_id, email_template_id;
```

Comment: @Ahmed Please check Thorsten's comment above.  I could not say it better myself if I tried.

Comment: In that case, just do `SELECT DISTINCT` with the same query I have given above.  But, your sample data does not actually show duplicate data (and hopefully you realize that).